# Простая печать из StringGrid

Tags: c++builder, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, нужно напечатать маленькую таблицу (StringGrid) самым простым способом.
Вот скрин программы:

[image]

**Обновление**

Хочу увидеть таблицу в таком же виде, как и в программе. Это вышло сделать с помощью:

```
if (PrintDialog1->Execute())
Printer()->BeginDoc();
this->StringGrid1->PaintTo(Printer()->Handle,10,10);
Printer()->EndDoc();
```

Но изображение на листе выходит очень мелкое, можете подсказать, как его увеличить?

Comment: А что Вы хотите увидеть в документе?

Comment: Хочу увидеть таблицу, в таком же виде как и в программе. Это вышло сделать с помощью: 

if (PrintDialog1->Execute())
Printer()->BeginDoc();
this->StringGrid1->PaintTo(Printer()->Handle,10,10);
Printer()->EndDoc();

Но изображение на листе выходит очень мелкое, можете подсказать как его увеличить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как простой вариант, запишите данные построчно в текстовый файл. Если необходим внешний вид таблицы, то пишите в формате HTML (табличная разметка). Затем при помощи функции `ShellExecute(NULL, "print", "абсолютный путь к файлу", NULL, NULL, SW_HIDE);`отправляйте на печать.

Comment: Я именно так всегда и делаю.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.